# python compare two large lists and process one

Tags: python, list, large-data

I have two text files. In a.txt,there are lines like this(one million lines):

```
991000000019999998,b10000021,
991000000019703408,b10000021,
991000545455435408,b10000045,
991000000029703408,b10000045,
...
```

the first part is barcode(991000000019703408), the second part is bib_number(b10000021).
Notice that the bib_number is possible to be duplicate in each line.But the barcode is unique. So using Set() I think is not okay.
In another file b.txt, the info only about bib_number(600 thousand record):

```
b10000021
b10000045
b10000215
...
```

Now I have to compare the two files,in a.txt,if eachline's bib_number (like b10000045) is not in b.txt, this whole line need to be output to c.txt, like(991000000029703408,b10000045,)

I write the code like this, but I have not got the reuslt until 20 mins.

```
with open("a.txt", "r") as f1,open("b.txt", "r") as f2,open("c.txt","w") as f3: 
    total_bb=f1.readlines() 
    list_match=f2.readlines() 
    for item_bb in total_bb:
        recordList=re.split(",",item_bb)
        item_bb_w=(recordList[1])+'\n'
        if item_bb_w not in list_match:
            f3.write(item_bb)
```

Is any tricks to do these two large lists comparison? Thanks

Comment: Do you care about order? If not just turn them into `set`s and `set1 - set2` will give you all the missing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `set`s, lookup is `O(1)`:

```
with open("a.txt", "r") as f1,open("b.txt", "r") as f2,open("c.txt","w") as f3:
    bs = set(b.strip() for b in f2)
    for a in f1:
        x = a.split(',')
        if x[1].strip() not in bs:
            f3.write(a)
```

I would also look at the `csv` module for reading comma separated values.

Comment: Notice that the bib_number is possible to be duplicate in each line. But the barcode is unique.(I have edited ) So using Set() I think is not okay. SET() will remove the same element . And I need output the whole line,not just the bib_number.Thanks

Comment: Updated to write out the whole of `a`.

Comment: @ AChampion shouldnt 'if x[1].strip() not in b" be "if x[1].strip() not in bs" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is very fast! Only takes approximately 3 seconds to get the results. BTW,why use set(b.strip() for b in f2) could improve the search speed obviously?

Comment: Lookup's in lists are `O(n)` vs lookups in sets are `O(1)`. Original approach was going to be `O(n^2)`.